# Chess tactics software which can read files

Tags: software, tactics, lichess

Lichess publishes tactics problems which can be [downloaded from database.lichess.org](https://database.lichess.org/lichess_db_puzzle.csv.bz2).

The file is in csv format. Which software can be used to read and play positions from this csv file?

Comment: lichess can do it itself if you have the game id - i didn't look into the csv  - it would be good if you add an example line to your question - i assume the game id is one of the columns. I also created an opensource python frontend http://lichess.bitplan.com/ which you could use as a basis for further work on this.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the file is described [here](https://database.lichess.org/#puzzles). According to this, the name of the columns are: PuzzleId, FEN, Moves, Rating, RatingDeviation, Popularity, NbPlays, Themes, GameUrl.

I do not know of any software to deal directly with this type of file. But (I see you're a software engineer) it's not difficult to write a snippet to convert the csv file (mainly columns FEN and Moves) to a pgn file that could be opened with any chess database manager.